# Move mysql databases to external drive on MAC OS (dealing with the absence of my.conf file)

Tags: macos, mac, mysql, database

I saw some solutions related to this problem but I think it still makes sense to ask since  nobody mentioned how this can be done in the absence of `my.conf` file in mysql default installation on MAC OS and also since the most proposed solutions are old. So here is the problem: my hard disk on my Mac (MAC OS High Sierra Version 10.13.6) does not have enough memory and I would like to move my MySQL data directory (mysql-8.0.17) to an external network drive called `/Volumes/passport/databases`. After searching for  solutions on Web, I plan to do the following:

(1) Identify Current MySQL Data Directory with `-uroot -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir"'` which gets  that the datadir path is `/usr/local/mysql/data/`

(2) Stop mysql server

(3) Copy all files in MySQL Data Directory to `/Volumes/passport/databases` by executing `cp -R -p /usr/local/mysql/data/  /Volumes/passport/databases`

(4) Configure a new MySQL Data Directory: under other OS, for this step we can change `my.conf` file content by changing the `mysqld` and `client` fields values to point to the new directory on external drive. However by default,  the OS X installation of mysql does not use a `my.cnf`, and MySQL just uses the default values. So I do not know how to perform this step on my MAC.

So my questions are:

(1) Are the steps described above are correct and sufficient for my purpose or am I missing something?

(2) As MAC OS installation of mysql does not  have a `my.conf` file, how the step (4) described above can be performed on my MAC?

I am also open to other/easier solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's way easier than I thought. The change of MySQL Data Directory path can be done directly (i.e., without using terminal) by opening MAC's System Preferences-> click on MySQL server icon (a dolphin) and then under "Configuration"->"Data directory" change the path to `/Volumes/passport/databases` (i.e. the external drive folder that I created for storing mysql databases). Hope this helps somebody with the same problem and saves her/his time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Had to use batchmod to change the permissions to that of mysql as owner and group and now the remote database folder works